# In React, what is the difference between using functional component and just a function, which returns React node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, function, components

I just wonder if these two ways of processing code work the same.

For me it seems easier to just create a regular function, which returns `React node`. It can also return `Array` of `React nodes`, which can be easily built up during function call.

Is there a reason to pick one over another? It looks like hooks can be used in both too...

```
export function Sandbox () {

    return <>
        <FunctionComponent animalName={'dog'} />
        {renderFunction('dog')}
    </>;
};

function FunctionComponent (props:{animalName:string}) {

    return <div>
        {props.animalName}
    </div>

}

function renderFunction (animalName:string) {

    return <div>
        {animalName}
    </div>

}
```

Thanks for tips :)

Comment: for starters, one would most likely choose a component over a function in order to organize their code.  Also if you need a function to contain its own state, such as a modal, etc. then that is a major benefit to using a component instead of a regular function.  I believe scalability is another reason I would outsource into a component rather than a function.  I feel that having a bunch of different functions inside of a page would get rather confusing and be difficult to maintain after awhile

Comment: also hooks cannot be called inside of a nested function that breaks the rules of hooks

Comment: Well, there does not have to be bunch of functions (they could branch finely), these functions could also be named with Capital letter as first, maybe even IDE could mark these functions returning nodes specifically with different color, there might be no need for that.

I understand some feelings, though I hope for a technically verificable proof. But still thanks for reply. O:-)

Comment: I am wondering, if React does not compile them the same in the end.

Comment: Hooks are JavaScript functions, but they impose two additional rules: Only call Hooks at the top level. Don't call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Only call Hooks from React function components.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#:~:text=Hooks%20are%20JavaScript%20functions%2C%20but,Hooks%20from%20React%20function%20components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence a function component *already is* just a function which returns a `ReactNode`.
Note that the return type `ReactNode` actually does already allow for arrays as well as `string`, etc.

```
type ReactText = string | number;
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;

interface ReactNodeArray extends Array<ReactNode> {}
type ReactFragment = {} | ReactNodeArray;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

The primary advantage of writing it as a function component is the ability to call the function using JSX syntax.  You can also make use of nested JSX to automatically set the `children` prop on your function.

You don't *need* to use JSX. In your example it would be fine to call `FunctionComponent({animalName: 'dog'})` (note: you cannot do this with class Components).  In that case the primary difference between it and `renderFunction('dog')` is that one puts all of its arguments into a single props object and the other doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will wait some time, but if there won't be any other answers, I will mark yours as correct. O:-)